# How do I get the correct datasource setup in app-maker?

Tags: database-design, google-app-maker

I'm trying to create an app with app maker but i keep running into blocking issues. Mostly due to the fact that I'm very new to this environment.

What I'm trying to create is an app that allows our administration to connect Teachers to courses they are teaching.
Keeping in mind that one course can be connected to several teachers and that teachers can have multiple courses connected to them.
Also there is a percentage that a course is given, while a teacher gets a certain amount of percentage (e.g. course A has a percentage of 60% and Teachers one gives this for 13%, teacher 2 for 27% and teacher 3 for 20%).

A teachers has the following info:

- Name
- Email
- Teaching percentage ( a total percentage set at creating the teaching info)

A course has the following info:

- Code
- Name
- Percentage ( a total percentage set at creating the course info)

Once these courses/teachers are created i need to connect a course to a teacher with a specific percentage ( not the total teaching percentage of the teacher and not the total percentage of the course, but a specific percentage for this course for this teacher)

Also I need to be able to have a page where I select a course and then get all the teachers connected to this course with the specific percentage ( not the total).

Can someone help me with the setup of the datasources? Up until now i created 2 datasource (Teachers and Courses, with a many-to-many relation between them, but I can't get it working.)

If additional information is required, please feel free to ask.